Парсинг selenium
Подскажите, как с помощью selenium нажать на кнопку "Применить фильтр" на сайте https://www.fl.ru/projects 
 
Кнопка псевдоэлемент ::before, никак не могу сделать это.
И еще один вопрос как при парсинге не учитывать закрепленные тикеты,

пробовал их скрывать нажатием на кнопку "скрыть все", но после того как скроет все равно парсит их.

a-parser сразу используйте, самописный парсер тяжело поддерживать
